# Return bool or char

Tags: c#, string, char

What I need is, checkChar(line[i]) to return false or char. So if result is not false, for loop works and if there is result, it breaks and prints out char.

I'm newbie to c#, so no idea how to do it. I tried this way.

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       Console.Write("Write a string: ");
       string line = Console.ReadLine();
       char result;
       if (line != null)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<=line.Length; i++){
                result = checkChar(line[i]);
                if(!result.Equals("#"))
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }    

    static char checkChar(char input){
        char[] letters={'f', 'g', 'h'};
        char noResult="#";
        foreach(char letter in letters){
            if(input.Equals(letter))
                return letter;
            else return noResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Getting error:

```
main.cs(18,31): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `result'
main.cs(24,14): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `char'
main.cs(22,17): error CS0161: `Program.checkChar(char)': not all code paths return a value
Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be bool? Why not null?

`char? noresult = null`

so the check would be

```
for(int i=0; i<=line.Length; i++){
    result = checkChar(line[i]);
    if(!result.HasValue)
        break;
}
```

Comment: could you explain downwotes?

Comment: I'm not downvoting. just write code with null please

Comment: I wrote this, http://www.sourcedrop.net/97uf6734a3f0c and getting errors http://www.sourcedrop.net/kMSf674a553ac

Comment: you have to use nullable type `char?`

Comment: 1. result is not initialized, make it `char? result = null;`
2. you have to use nullable type `char?`
3. add `return null` to end, if the `foreach` wont run you have no return

Answer (score 5):

```
 char noResult="#";
```

should be

```
 char noResult= '#';
```

`""` denotes a string where as `''` denotes a char.

Should the method not be the following?

```
static char checkChar(char input){
        char[] letters={'f', 'g', 'h'};
        char noResult="#";
        foreach(char letter in letters){
            if(input.Equals(letter))
                return letter;
        }
        return noResult;
    }
```

So once the foreach has completed the iteration of `letters`, `noResult` gets returned rather than before the iteration has completed?
This way you are always returning a result even if a `char` has not been found.

Comment: Can you please help me to modify this funtion to return bool or char?

Comment: Once you make that change it should be able to return the value correctly

Comment: I wrote this, http://www.sourcedrop.net/97uf6734a3f0c and getting errors http://www.sourcedrop.net/kMSf674a553ac

Comment: I have added an updated sample of code, give it a try

Answer (score 3):

In order to return a `bool` the usual way to do this is to use an `out` parameter:

```
static bool checkChar(char input, out char output){
    char[] letters={'f', 'g', 'h'};
    char noResult = '#';
    foreach(char letter in letters){
        if(input.Equals(letter))
        {
            // this is okay. Continue.
        }
        else
        {
            output = noResult;
            return false;
        }
    }

    output = letter;
    return true;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
char output;
if (checkChar('?', out output))
{
    // valid, do something
}
```

Comment: You should rectify the mistake which Ric has mentioned.

Comment: This follows the pattern of the TryParse method, which is a sound way of handling the issue in question!

Answer (score 1):

**Result error**: You are creating a result variable of type char.
The value of result is null at first.

Then you initialize it inside the if, and use it afterwards BUT if "line" equals null, then result is never initialized, therefore you are using a Console.WriteLine(null).

**For the conversion error**

```
char noResult="#";
```

The # should be enclosed in single quotation marks '#'

Then, **not all paths returning a value** is because the CheckChar has no stand alone return clause, this means that if letters is null (you and I know it is not, but the compiler does not), then the foreach never gets executed, therefore no return will be called.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.  None of them are exactly what you want, but if you write the caller correctly, they can solve the same Problem.

- Return a nullable char  (`char?`, or `System.Nullable<char>`).  This can be either a `char` or a `null` reference.
- Return a string instead of a `char`, return the empty string instead of `false`.
- Use the Unicode code-Point 0 (`'\0'`) instead of `false`.

In most cases I would return a string, but either of the other two might be the right solution for some problems.

Comment: As @PatrickHoffman notes, you can also use an `out` Parameter.  I left that off my list, because I personally don't like them, but they are another valid solution.

Comment: Null is what I want. I wrote this, http://www.sourcedrop.net/97uf6734a3f0c and getting errors http://www.sourcedrop.net/kMSf674a553ac

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code...

```
void Main()
{
           string line = Console.ReadLine();
           bool result;
           for(int i=0; i<line.Length; i++)
           {
               result = checkChar(line[i]);
               if(!result)
                   continue;
                Console.WriteLine(line[i]);
            }
}


static bool checkChar(char input)
{
   char[] letters={'f', 'g', 'h'};
   return letters.Contains(input);
}
```

Comment: I need exact character that input contains no just true or false

Comment: True means that line[i] is a character that you need and false means that it is some other character. (# in your case)

Answer (score 0):

When defining variable, assign a default value. for example:

```
char result = char.MinValue;
```

Also change checkChar method like this:

```
static char checkChar(char input){
        char[] letters={'f', 'g', 'h'};
        char result='#';
        foreach(char letter in letters){
            if(input.Equals(letter))
              result = letter;  
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
    {
       Console.Write("Write a string: ");
       string line = Console.ReadLine();
       object result;
       if (line != null)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<=line.Length; i++){
                result = checkChar(line[i]);
                if(result is bool)
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }    

    static object checkChar(char input){
        char[] letters={'f', 'g', 'h'};
        char noResult="#";
        foreach(char letter in letters){
            if(input.Equals(letter))
                return letter;
            else return false;
        }
    }
```